# is there an R function to change more than one variable names in part only based on a condition?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have a data set with variables that represent several aspects of an individual, separated by a hyphen. I have been using the dplyr package 'select'and 'contains' function to summarise by each aspect.

However one aspect can be described as 'other' and specified in another column. I want to be able to change part of the variable name to reflect the entry in this other column.

for example:

```
#Key: b = big; s = small
> #   : g = green, p = purple, o = other
> 
> oth<- c("red", NA, NA, "yellow")
> b_g<- c(1, 2, 3, 2)
> s_g<- c(2, 3, 1, 4)
> b_p<- c(1, 2, 3, 2)
> s_p<- c(2, 3, 1, 4)
> b_o<- c(3, 0, 0, 1)
> s_o<- c(2, 0, 0, 4)
> 
> 
> df<- data.frame(oth, b_g, s_g, b_p, s_p, b_o, s_o)
> df
     oth b_g s_g b_p s_p b_o s_o
1    red   1   2   1   2   3   2
2   <NA>   2   3   2   3   0   0
3   <NA>   3   1   3   1   0   0
4 yellow   2   4   2   4   1   4
> 
> #To summerise for green only I would use: 
> 
> green<- df %>% select(contains("_g")) %>% mutate(totalg = rowSums(.[1:2]))
> summary(green$totalg)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   3.00    3.75    4.50    4.50    5.25    6.00 
>
```

I want to change the names of the variables in the data frame so that it picks up from the other column, if possible transforming it on the way (e.g. coding "red" to "r") so that I end up with the following

```
df
     oth b_g s_g b_p s_p b_o s_o b_r s_r b_y s_y
1    red   1   2   1   2   3   2   3   2   0   0
2   <NA>   2   3   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   <NA>   3   1   3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
4 yellow   2   4   2   4   1   4   0   0   1   4
```

I would be very grateful for any advice. First time posting so apologies if I have left anything out

Comment: Hi @pcompston! I have to be honest, some parts in your description are rather cunfused.. First of all, I think that the way you create your initial data.frame (that you described in the first paragraph) can be probably improved and it would make your analysis easier. I think you should add an edit at the end with the data you have at the beginning and how you get to the data you have now. Second, back to your problem, what it the columns `oth`? Also, can you rephrase the sencente "I want to change... following". I didnt get it at all.

Comment: Do you have a lot of values in `oth` or only a couple?  I can imagine a way forward using the relatively new `across()` function but it would involve using `ifelse()` for the different values of `oth` and that would be a burden if you have lots of other values.  In terms of the question, good job making a reproducible example on your first try!  It can help to use package **reprex** to get a copy of the code and output to paste here so that folks can copy and paste the whole code section into R and immediately run things.  I had to delete all the "> " from your code.

Comment: thanks -the solution below solved the problem, good tip about the > signs, I'll remember that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given your example for a desired output, how does this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df2 <- df %>%
    split(coalesce(oth,'NA')) %>%
    imap(~{
        if(.y == 'NA') return(.x %>% select(-ends_with('_o')))
        colnames(.x) <- gsub('(?<=_)o', substr(.y,1,1), colnames(.x), perl = T)
        .x
    }) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    mutate(across(.cols = where(is.numeric), .fns = ~coalesce(.,0)))
```

The `split` does mix up the order of the entries, however.

If that is to be avoided, the following also works, I think:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3 <- df %>%
    nest(other_cols = ends_with('_o')) %>%
    mutate(
    other_cols = map2(other_cols, oth, ~{
        if(is.na(.y)) return(tibble())
        colnames(.x) <- gsub('(?<=_)o', substr(.y,1,1), colnames(.x), perl = T)
        .x
      })
    ) %>%
    unnest(other_cols, keep_empty = T) %>%
    mutate(across(.cols = where(is.numeric), .fns = ~coalesce(.,0)))
```

Comment: This second solution worked like a charm - thank you so so much! I am very grateful.

Comment: happy to hear! well, feel free to accept the answer, then :)